# Result in Node.JS Addon is different with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I want to convert a wchar_t into a normal string. When I output the text in Visual Studio I get the correct text back. As soon as I do the same in my Node.JS addon, strange characters come back. Why is that so?

```cpp
std::string ws_to_UTF8 (const wchar_t *ws)
{
    std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8 <wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes (ws);
}

...

const int bufferSize = 1024;
wchar_t textBuffer[bufferSize];
int copied = SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);
printf("Copied %d chars.\n", copied);
printf("getting text:\n");

printf("%s \n", ws_to_UTF8(textBuffer).c_str());

// Output in Visual Studio (correct):Kein Papier / Kassette falsch eingesetzt!

// Pr├╝fen Sie, ob das Papier richtig in das Papierfach eingelegt und ob das Papierfach richtig installiert ist.

// Output in Node.JS
// µòïµ╣®ÕÇáþüíµò®Ôü▓ÔÇ»µàïþì│þæÑµò┤µÿáµ▒íµì│Ôü¿µÑÑµØ«þìÑþæÑþæ║Ó┤íÓ┤èÕÇè´▒▓µòªÔü«µÑôÔ▒Ñµ╝áÔüóµàñÔü│µàÉµÑ░þëÑþêáµì®þæ¿µØ®µñáÔü«µàñÔü│µàÉµÑ░þëÑµàªµíúµöáµ╣®µòºµò¼þæºþöáµæ«µ╝áÔüóµàñÔü│µàÉµÑ░þëÑµàªµíúþêáµì®þæ¿µØ®µñáþì«µà┤µ▒¼µò®þæ▓µñáþæ│.þë»K
```

Comment: This seems to be dependent on the nodejs addon - how is it implementing this function?

Comment: I compiled it using node-gyp or what do you mean? @SethKitchen

Comment: You're not getting the same number of characters copied correct? So it's not in your conversion function, I think it's because of SendMessage -- which might fail with NodeGyp because NodeGyp is cross platform and SendMessage is windows only... I'm just guessing

Comment: @SethKitchen But the copied int gives the right amount of chars back.